# Is there any way to fire heartbeat API from for website visitors?

Tags: plugin-development, heartbeat-api

I saw that Heartbeat API is fired when someone is logged in the Wordpress. Is there any way to fire it for website visitors?

Comment: yes there is. I suggest you edit the question and ask about the actual question you have

Comment: Can you let me know how can I do that?

Comment: what for? It is meaningless for non logged in users, and it will bring your site down

Comment: My bad. I totally agree with you & after posting this even I realized the same. But can you still let me know just for the sake of curiosity that how this is even done?

Comment: you probably just need to figure out which JS file it is and enqueue it, you can find the handle as the id used for the script when inspecting the HTML. (sorry, do not have it off the top of my head and too lazy to look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Kaplun says in the comments, you shouldn't do it. But here's how to enqueue the heartbeat script for all users on the public side... if you really, really want to overload your server.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_heartbeat' );
function enqueue_heartbeat() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'heartbeat', includes_url( js/heartbeat.js ) );
}
```